# grep invert match on two files

Tags: grep

I have two text files containing one column each, for example -

File_A       File_B

1              1

2              2

3              8

If I do `grep -f File_A File_B > File_C`, I get File_C containing 1 and 2. I want to know how to use grep -v on two files so that I can get the non-matching values, 3 and 8 in the above example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `comm` if it allows empty output delimiter

```
$ # -3 means suppress lines common to both input files
$ # by default, tab character appears before lines from second file
$ comm -3 f1 f2
3
    8
$ # change it to empty string
$ comm -3 --output-delimiter='' f1 f2
3
8
```

Note: `comm` requires sorted input, so use `comm -3 --output-delimiter='' <(sort f1) <(sort f2)` if they are not already sorted

You can also pass common lines got from `grep` as input to `grep -v`. Tested with `GNU grep`, some version might not support all these options

```
$ grep -Fxf f1 f2 | grep -hxvFf- f1 f2
3
8
```

- `-F` option to match strings literally, not as regex
- `-x` option to match whole lines only
- `-h` to suppress file name prefix
- `f-` to accept `stdin` instead of file input

Comment: Both of these methods work very well. Just what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=$0;next} !($0 in a) {print a[(FNR)], $0}' f1 f2
3 8
```

To Understand the meaning of `NR` and `FNR` check below output of their print.

```
awk '{print NR,FNR}' f1 f2
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 1
6 2
7 3
8 4
```

Condition `NR==FNR` is used to extract the data from first file as both `NR` and `FNR` would be same for first file only.

Comment: Thanks for the awk way of doing it. I am very new to it. Could you please tell me what si NR and FNR?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `diff` command (to compare files line by line):

```
diff --suppress-common-lines -y f1 f2 | column -t
```

The output (left column contain lines from `f1`, right column - from `f2`):

```
3  |  8
```

---

`-y, --side-by-side` - output in two columns